# Hide selected option in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Sorry guys, my question was not so good asked, because my english is also not good But now i will write it better, I have 1 dropdown with 5 options: appel, banaan, peer and 2 more. you can also add more dropdowns when you click on 'nieuw product'. okay now when i open the first dropdown and select appel, i want it to be disabled in my second dropdown.

Here i have jsfiddle link with the full code. but im stuck in the code. please help me

https://jsfiddle.net/h8djru2o/

```
var $select = $('<select>').addClass('keuzes');
$select.append('<option>Kies je optie</option>');
$select.append('<option value="appel">Appel</option>');
$select.append('<option value="banaan">Banaan</option>');
$select.append('<option value="peer">Peer</option>');
$select.append('<option value="mandarijn">Mandarijn</option>');
$select.append('<option value="sinasappel">Sinasappel</option>');


$select.on('change', function () {
    //Other code goes here
});
```

Comment: What option should be hidden?

Comment: like when user select appel, then when he adds a new product, he can not select appel again

Comment: remove the apple from the list of items

Comment: no it needs to be disabled

Answer (score 0):

Once try this..

```
$('#myselectbox').click(function() {
     $(this).find('option:selected').remove();
 });
```

::::::: EDIT:::::::

I've tried like this and it's working fine...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#alpha').click(function() {
            $(this).find('option:selected').remove();
        });
    });
</script>

</head>

<body>

    <select name="alpha" id="alpha">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
        <option value="D">D</option>
    </select>

</body>
</html>
```

Once compare with this code, and check if you are missing anything.. Here the JQuery code should be kept in `$(document).ready(function(){});`. Did you do that ?

Comment: ID should be with # `#productprijzen`, i think you gave `.` over there..

Comment: its working, but it is removing the wrong one?                                                               Here is the JSfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/h8djru2o/2/